# How can I process an array using TikZ 2.00 syntax?

Tags: tikz-pgf, programming, arrays

I use TikZ/PGF 2.00. In the CVS PGF manual pag. 563 we have

```
\def\myarray{{1,"two",2+1,"IV","cinq","sechs",sin(\i*5)*14}}
\foreach \i in {0,...,6}{\pgfmathparse{\myarray[\i]}\pgfmathresult, }
```

My question is: How can do the same but in TikZ/PGF 2.00?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use them directly:

```
\foreach \i/\foo in {0/1, 1/two, 2/{2+1}, 3/IV, 4/cinq, 5/sechs, 6/{sin(6*5)*14}}
```

or use `arrayjobx` package insdead.

Comment: in all cases error. i use pgf/tikz 2.0. and arrayjobx

Answer (score 2):

With PGF 2.0 you could define the array differently and process it outside of `\pgfmathparse`.

For example:

```
\def\myarray{{1},{"two"},{2+1},{"IV"},{"cinq"},{"sechs"},{sin(6*5)*14}}
\foreach \i in \myarray {\pgfmathparse{\i}\pgfmathresult,}
```

Or with a loop index:

```
\def\myarray{0/{1},1/{"two"},2/{2+1},3/{"IV"},4/{"cinq"},5/{"sechs"},6/{sin(\i*5)*14}}
\foreach \i\element in \myarray {\pgfmathparse{\element}\pgfmathresult,}
```

I tested both and got

> 1,two,3.0,IV,cinq,sechs,7.0,